# How to format response to jQuery AutoComplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

Im trying to use jQuery AutoComplete but all i get is a single item with all results all in it.

I have this ASP.Net WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string FetchCompletionList(string term)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CustomerProvider.FetchKeys(term, 8));
    return json;
}
```

being called by this script:

```
$("[id$='txtLKey']").autocomplete({
            minlength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) {

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Views/Crm/Json/Json.aspx/FetchCompletionList",
                    data: '{term: "' + $("[id$='txtLKey']") .val() + '", count: "8"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                       alert(textStatus);
                       alert(errorThrown.toString());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

And the result is this:

[image]

When what I actually want is a list of options the user can select i.e. each NZ should be an item in a list.

Comment: Can you share the value returned from the server? use firebug/developer tools in the browser to see the response

Comment: See thats what I dont understand. There is no label/value its just an array of strings not a dictionary. The docs http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default feed an array of strings into the widget as source. Why does the remotely returned data need to have extra "meaningless" fluff in the form of a dictionary? As far as I can see the docs dont identify any neeeed to have a different format for remotely returned data. thx

Comment: sorry the statement I made was wrong, autocomplete internally normalizes the input passed to `response`. Then the reason might be the `data` may not be a array, it might be a string. Can you use `console.log(data)` and see what is printing

Comment: {"d":"[\"NZ0008\",\"NZ0015\",\"NZ0017\",\"NZ0018\",\"NZ0026\",\"NZ0027\",\"NZ0031\",\"NZ0035\"]"} *from firebug*

Comment: There are two problems here, 1. you need to pass `data.d` to response `response(data.d);` also your value string is invalid it should be `{"d":["NZ0008","NZ0015","NZ0017","NZ0018","NZ0026","NZ0027","NZ003??1","NZ0035"]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here,

1. you need to pass `data.d` to `response` like `response(data.d)`.
2. your value string is invalid it should be `{"d":["NZ0008","NZ0015","NZ0017","NZ0018","NZ0026","NZ0027","NZ003??1","NZ0035"‌​]}`

Comment: Ok if i pass data.d I get nothing for auto complete. i.e. no list. I think the escapes in the firebug output are put in there by firebug. they dont show up in console.log.

Comment: The test case will be to hard code the data and see what is happening like add the like `data = {"d":["NZ0008","NZ0015","NZ0017","NZ0018","NZ0026","NZ0027","NZ003??1","NZ0035"‌​]}` before `response(data);`

Comment: AFAIK `console.log` will not add any escape characters also you can use the net tab in the firfox to see the actual response from server

Comment: I had quotes around the array.... plus I didn't have data.d, just data ;( Thx alot.